# top bar button of the view controller doesn't appear

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following:

*I push a view controller into a navigationController like this:*

```
 moviePlayer = [[[CustomMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithPath:path2] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [moviePlayer readyPlayer];
```

And is loaded up a video which has no button on the top bar.

[image]

After I comeback to the previous view and try again to load up this view, it shows this:

[image]

Suddenly the *Done* button appears in the top bar.

My question is why doesn't it appear from this first time, cause I'm not changing the code.

This is the code of the viewController pushed into the stack:

```
@implementation CustomMoviePlayerViewController

- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    // Unless state is unknown, start playback
    if ([mp loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
    {
        // Remove observer
        [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] 
         removeObserver:self
         name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
         object:nil];
        [[mp view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 400)];
        [mp setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];

        // Add movie player as subview
        [[self view] addSubview:[mp view]];   

        // Play the movie
        [mp play];
    }
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
{    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    // Remove observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
     object:nil];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}

- (void) readyPlayer
{
    mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
    {
        // Set movie player layout
        [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
        [mp setFullscreen:YES];

        // May help to reduce latency
        [mp prepareToPlay];

        // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }  
    else
    {
        // Register to receive a notification when the movie is in memory and ready to play.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Thank you!:)